In 1 John 4:6, what does the author specifically say is the difference between the spirit of truth and the spirit of error?
1 John 4:2-8 KJV

2 Hereby know ye the Spirit of God: Every spirit that confesseth that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is of God:
3 And every spirit that confesseth not that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is not of God: and this is that spirit of antichrist, whereof ye have heard that it should come; and even now already is it in the world.
4 Ye are of God, little children, and have overcome them: because greater is he that is in you, than he that is in the world.
5 They are of the world: therefore speak they of the world, and the world heareth them.
6 We are of God: he that knoweth God heareth us; he that is not of God heareth not us. Hereby know we the spirit of truth, and the spirit of error.
7 Beloved, let us love one another: for love is of God; and every one that loveth is born of God, and knoweth God.
8 He that loveth not knoweth not God; for God is love.

In verses 2-3, John tells us how was can discern the difference between the Spirit of God and the spirit of antichrist.
In verse 6, he says "hereby know we" ("this is how we know") how to tell the difference between the spirit of truth and the spirit of error. It would seem that the use of the word spirit in verse 6, specifically references the discussion of the spirit of God/antichrist that directly precedes the verse.
However, the language found in verses 7 and 8 appear to mirror the pattern in verses 2 and 3, ie one type of person exhibits one trait and the other type of person exhibits another trait.
It seems to me that verse 6 ("this is how we know") is alluding to both sets of verses where those who accept that personhood of Jesus Christ are those who keep His command to love others.
My question is: what does the grammatical structure say verse 6 (this is how we know the difference between the spirit of truth and the spirit of error) is specifically referring to, ie the verses preceding it or following?

Firstly, depending on one's viewpoint, it was either the Almighty, Himself, or it was the Word/Logos that became incarnate, or a combination of the two, or even three if one brings the "Spirit" of both into the equation. It certainly was not Jesus, per se. Jesus is a - product of becoming - the "Son of Man" and once born of "Man" then became Yehoshua/Immanuel (Jesus), meaning "Yahweh/Jehovah is Salvation", which in turn means "God with us", at least in the sense of being God's representative. Can you at least agree "in principle", as to when Jesus, Himself, came into "being", as it were?

If you can answer honestly here to the above, I can then consider commenting further or even give answer to the above. I can't even vote on this at this point.

As in English, the word πνεῦμα = "spirit" is a very "versatile" word with a large range of meanings (as the OP would know) that include (see BDAG for details):

air/wind
that which animates or gives life to the body
a part of the human personality, eg, "attitude"
a non-corporeal entity such as an angel or demon
God's influence in our lives
the Holy Spirit
etc

In 1 John 4:6 we have two distinct titles placed in grammatical contradistinction:

τὸ πνεῦμα τῆς ἀληθείας = "the spirit of the truth"
τὸ πνεῦμα τῆς πλάνης = "the spirit of the error/deception" which occurs only here in 1 John 4:6, but clearly alludes to Jesus' comments about Satan in John 8:44

First, "Spirit of Truth" is a technical title for the Holy Spirit" that occurs only in the John's writings, John 14:16, 17, 15:26, 16:13, 15.  Thus, I assume that in 1 John 4:6, John is specifically referring to the Holy Spirit as the Spirit of Truth.
"Every spirit" (V1) is a grammatically singular refer to a collective group of people with various motivations energized with various intentions that flow from either the Spirit of Truth or the Spirit of falsehood, ie, Satan and his minions; specifically, either true prophets or false prophets (V1).
In V2, John again refers to the Holy Spirit as "The Spirit of God" (lit: "the Spirit of the God" ensuring a monadic singular).  John is saying that any teacher/prophet who declares that Jesus came in the flesh is motivated by the Spirit of God.
In V3 John introduces us the "the antichrist", again in grammatical monadic distinction - a reference to Satan and the way he inspires his false prophets.
In V4, John distinguishes between these two spirits: viz, the Spirit of God vs the spirit of antichrist.
This is summarized the the following table



Holy Spirit
Satan




Spirit of God, Spirit of Truth
spirit of antichrist, spirit of falsehood


true prophets teach Jesus came in the flesh
false prophets do not teach that Jesus came in the flesh


disciples are "of God"
disciples are "of the world"



APPENDIX - Grammatical "Monadic"
In his magnum opus, "Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics", Wallace spends a large section of his book on the grammatical function of the Greek article.  If I simplify his excellent and extensive material to a very (overly) brief summary, the Greek article has the following functions:

it is anaphoric, ie, refers back to a previous inarticular noun and thus serves as identification
it indicates an abstract idea
it serves to identify something that is "monadic', ie, the only person/thing in its class.

It is this last case that is frequently does with "God" and "Satan" in the NT.  For example, in Matt 1:23 we have the first instance of the noun theos/God in the NT and is thus monadic - Jesus is given the title "The God".
The same is true of Σατανᾶς, "Satan", in almost all cases except where it is vocative.

Thanks Dottard, I reread your response again and see that you believe v6b refers back to v2-3. How do you view v7-8? Do they further define the spirit of truth and the spirit of error, ie where those who have the spirit of truth would love others and those who deny the humanity of Christ also do not love other people? I don't see v7 as beginning a new thought. v7-8 define who knows God and who doesn't (matching the context of v2-3 and who is "of God" and who is not.

@alb - I would beg to differ and think that V7 begins a new section: V106 establishes that God and the Holy Spirit are the only source of truth (as opposed to Satan who is the source of error).  V7 begins a new section that says that (1) God is the ultimate source of love and all God's true followers must participate in and share that love; and that this can only be done by God's Spirit.


"is a technical title for the Holy Spirit" - based on what evidence? &  "I assume that in 1 John 4:6, John is specifically referring to the Holy Spirit"  - your A is based on these 2 assumptions / own opinion with no evidence.


@anothertheory - OK - just listed all the evidence in the answer because it contains ALL the times the phrase "The spirit of truth" occurs and all refer to the Holy Spirit.  John 14:16, 17, 15:26, 16:13, 15

@Dottard you already had that.  Noting there shows evidence that this relates to the HS?  14:16 - says 'helper' - 17 say spirit of truth - 15:26 says 'helper' 'spirit of truth' - 16:15 doesn’t even mention spirit - 16:13 says 'spirit of truth' TO COME! – HS here from the beginning.  This is not evidence

@anothertheory - the paraketos (= helper/advocate, etc) is the Holy Spirit.  John 14:26.  That is rather basic!

@ Dottard - I understand your point but think we need to consider where the spirit/love context begins. Go look at chapter 3. Love is introduced, (V11) and V19 tells you that we can tell we're of the truth if we love the brethren.  V23 established the commandment that Jesus gave us (which is to love) and V24 tells us those that keep that commandment dwells in Christ. Also please notice all the usages of "hereby" and "herein" in chapters 3 & 4.

@Dottard No evidence again that helper/advocate equates to HS - you just want to make it that to fit the 3 in 1.  But problems arise with passages like 16:13 But when He the, Spirit of truth, shall come, &  John 16:7 Unless I go away, the Advocate will not come to you;  etc… HS here from the beginning.


My question is: what does the grammatical structure say verse 6 (this is how we know the difference between the spirit of truth and the spirit of error) is specifically referring to, ie the verses preceding it or following?

And

What does the author specifically say is the difference between the Spirit of Truth and the spirit of error?

Understanding verse 6 requires us to understand John's purpose in writing. The verse must be placed in context. It's not just looking at verses 4:2 or 4:3.
Looking at the opening statement of John's topic and looking at the conclusion informs us of John's goal for this passage which colors all the meaning in between.
Looking at the passage there is a content structure, a beginning, a middle, and an end
Beginning: 1 John 3:7a introduces the topic.

"Dear children, do not let anyone lead you astray..." NIV

End From here to the conclusion of the letter - 1 John 5:13 - John explains how followers of Jesus can know that they have eternal life.

13 I write these things to you who believe in the name of the Son of God so that you may know that you have eternal life.

1 John 4:6 is part of a larger passage - verses preceding 4:6 and following 4:6 that make up instructions for followers of Jesus:

To prevent them from being led astray
That they may know they have eternal life.

Middle Summary
In order to help his readers gain this understanding John assembles a series of comparisons that - when taken together - provide the full picture of a confident follower of Jesus vs those who are led astray.
1 John 4:6 contributes to, clarifies and supports the verses both preceding it and following.
Here is an incomplete list of the comparisons in the passage.
1 John 3
v1-2 righteous vs sin
v10 children of God vs children of the devil
v19-21 our hearts do not condemn us vs our hearts condemn us
1 John 4
v2-3 Spirit of God who acknowledges Jesus vs spirit of the antichrist
v5-6 from God vs from the world
v5-6 listens to those who are from God vs not listening to those who are from God
v6b Spirit of Truth vs spirit of falsehood
v7-8 those who love vs those who do not love
V13-16 to those who live in God have been given his Spirit and they acknowledge Jesus is the Son of God (no "vs")
v17-18 confidence on the day of judgement, no fear vs fear
And others....
So we see that - specifically - the Spirit of Truth:

loves others
are righteous
are children of God
live in God
have been given his Spirit
acknowledge Jesus is the Son of God
listens to those who are from God
have confidence on the day of judgement - no fear
And others...

The spirit of falshood:

is sinful
is a child of the devil
hearts condemn them
does not acknowledge Jesus
is from the world
does not listen to those who are from God
is not loving
are fearful on the day of judgement
And others...

The whole passage works together like brush strokes in a painting to give us a full and rich picture.

Middle In detail
An outline of the passage to illustrate the structure would require me to try to summarize each section. Rather than shortening each section in my own words I have taken the complete passage, removing all the line breaks provided by the NIV, and adding line breaks where the content indicates an instruction that relates back to 1 John 3:7a.
Another reader may see a better way to format by instruction but my hope is to illustrate the structure well enough to make the point.

1 John 3
7 Dear children, do not let anyone lead you astray.
The one who does what is right is righteous, just as he is righteous. 8 The one who does what is sinful is of the devil, because the devil has been sinning from the beginning. The reason the Son of God appeared was to destroy the devil’s work. 9 No one who is born of God will continue to sin, because God’s seed remains in them; they cannot go on sinning, because they have been born of God.
10 This is how we know who the children of God are and who the children of the devil are: Anyone who does not do what is right is not God’s child, nor is anyone who does not love their brother and sister.
11 For this is the message you heard from the beginning: We should love one another. 12 Do not be like Cain, who belonged to the evil one and murdered his brother. And why did he murder him? Because his own actions were evil and his brother’s were righteous. 13 Do not be surprised, my brothers and sisters, if the world hates you. 14 We know that we have passed from death to life, because we love each other. Anyone who does not love remains in death. 15 Anyone who hates a brother or sister is a murderer, and you know that no murderer has eternal life residing in him.
16 This is how we know what love is: Jesus Christ laid down his life for us. And we ought to lay down our lives for our brothers and sisters. 17 If anyone has material possessions and sees a brother or sister in need but has no pity on them, how can the love of God be in that person? 18 Dear children, let us not love with words or speech but with actions and in truth.
19 This is how we know that we belong to the truth and how we set our hearts at rest in his presence: 20 If our hearts condemn us, we know that God is greater than our hearts, and he knows everything. 21 Dear friends, if our hearts do not condemn us, we have confidence before God 22 and receive from him anything we ask, because we keep his commands and do what pleases him. 23 And this is his command: to believe in the name of his Son, Jesus Christ, and to love one another as he commanded us. 24 The one who keeps God’s commands lives in him, and he in them.
And this is how we know that he lives in us: We know it by the Spirit he gave us.
1 John 4
1 Dear friends, do not believe every spirit, but test the spirits to see whether they are from God, because many false prophets have gone out into the world.
2 This is how you can recognize the Spirit of God: Every spirit that acknowledges that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh is from God, 3 but every spirit that does not acknowledge Jesus is not from God. This is the spirit of the antichrist, which you have heard is coming and even now is already in the world.
4 You, dear children, are from God and have overcome them, because the one who is in you is greater than the one who is in the world. 5 They are from the world and therefore speak from the viewpoint of the world, and the world listens to them. 6 We are from God, and whoever knows God listens to us; but whoever is not from God does not listen to us.
This is how we recognize the Spirit of truth and the spirit of falsehood.
7 Dear friends, let us love one another, for love comes from God. Everyone who loves has been born of God and knows God. 8 Whoever does not love does not know God, because God is love.
9 This is how God showed his love among us: He sent his one and only Son into the world that we might live through him. 10 This is love: not that we loved God, but that he loved us and sent his Son as an atoning sacrifice for our sins. 11 Dear friends, since God so loved us, we also ought to love one another. 12 No one has ever seen God; but if we love one another, God lives in us and his love is made complete in us.
13 This is how we know that we live in him and he in us: He has given us of his Spirit. 14 And we have seen and testify that the Father has sent his Son to be the Savior of the world. 15 If anyone acknowledges that Jesus is the Son of God, God lives in them and they in God. 16 And so we know and rely on the love God has for us.
God is love. Whoever lives in love lives in God, and God in them.
17 This is how love is made complete among us so that we will have confidence on the day of judgment: In this world we are like Jesus. 18 There is no fear in love. But perfect love drives out fear, because fear has to do with punishment. The one who fears is not made perfect in love.
19 We love because he first loved us. 20 Whoever claims to love God yet hates a brother or sister is a liar. For whoever does not love their brother and sister, whom they have seen, cannot love God, whom they have not seen. 21 And he has given us this command: Anyone who loves God must also love their brother and sister.
1 John 5
1 Everyone who believes that Jesus is the Christ is born of God, and everyone who loves the father loves his child as well.
2 This is how we know that we love the children of God: by loving God and carrying out his commands. 3 In fact, this is love for God: to keep his commands. And his commands are not burdensome, 4 for everyone born of God overcomes the world. This is the victory that has overcome the world, even our faith. 5 Who is it that overcomes the world? Only the one who believes that Jesus is the Son of God.
6 This is the one who came by water and blood—Jesus Christ. He did not come by water only, but by water and blood. And it is the Spirit who testifies, because the Spirit is the truth. 7 For there are three that testify: 8 the Spirit, the water and the blood; and the three are in agreement. 9 We accept human testimony, but God’s testimony is greater because it is the testimony of God, which he has given about his Son. 10 Whoever believes in the Son of God accepts this testimony. Whoever does not believe God has made him out to be a liar, because they have not believed the testimony God has given about his Son. 11 And this is the testimony: God has given us eternal life, and this life is in his Son. 12 Whoever has the Son has life; whoever does not have the Son of God does not have life.


You never answered my question.

@alb I've taken another stab at being clearer.

I think you're dancing around the main point. Jesus' instructions about His commandment to us (love others) is central (chapter 3 v23-24). Everything else supports that.
